# problem with collision in kivy (simulating gravity)

Tags: python, kivy, collision-detection

I have a simple code in kivy where the ball bounces off the paddle and what i would like to achieve is make ball grounded after the bouncing of the ball ends. So i would like to simulate gravity. Problem is that collide_widget does not detect collision properly. I expect collide_widget will detect collision when ball.y == paddle.top but it detect collision when ball.y < paddle.top and it is always different depending on starting position of ball.

gravity.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock

DELTA_TIME = 1.0 / 60.0

class Ball(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

    def move(self, dt):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) *dt + self.pos

class Paddle(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

    def move(self, dt):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) *dt  + self.pos

class GravityBall(Ball):
    def update(self, dt, idle):
        if idle == 0:
            self.velocity_y -= 20
            self.move(dt)
        else: 
            self.velocity_y = 0
            self.move(dt)

class GravityGame(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.idle = 0
        self.ball = GravityBall()
        self.ball.center = (200,300)
        self.add_widget(self.ball)

        self.paddle = Paddle()
        self.paddle.center = (200,100)
        self.add_widget(self.paddle)

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, DELTA_TIME)

    def update(self, dt): 

        self.ball.update(dt, self.idle) 
        self.paddle.move(dt) 
        
        if self.ball.collide_widget(self.paddle) and self.ball.y+5 >= self.paddle.top:
            self.ball.velocity_y *= -1
            self.idle = 0     
        elif self.ball.collide_widget(self.paddle) and self.ball.y+5 < self.paddle.top:
            self.idle = 1


class GravityApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GravityGame()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GravityApp().run()
```

gravity.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.1

<GravityBall>:
    size: 30, 30
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<Paddle>:
    size: 100, 30
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `collide_point()` method is not likely to capture the exact moment when your ball touches the paddle, so you must an approximation. Here is a modified version of your `GravityGame` class that does so:

```
class GravityGame(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.idle = 0
        self.ball = GravityBall()
        self.ball.center = (200, 300)
        self.add_widget(self.ball)

        self.paddle = Paddle()
        self.paddle.center = (200, 100)
        self.add_widget(self.paddle)

        self.sched = Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, DELTA_TIME)  # save a reference to this event

    def update(self, dt):

        self.ball.update(dt, self.idle)
        self.paddle.move(dt)

        # capture approximate collision event
        if self.ball.collide_widget(self.paddle):
            self.ball.y = self.paddle.top  # adjust ball position to top of paddle
            self.ball.velocity_y *= -0.75  # collision is not perfectly elastic, so use a value between 0 and -1

            # check if ball velocity is nearly stopped (does not move a single pixel in an interval)
            if self.ball.velocity_y * DELTA_TIME < 1.0:
                self.idle = 1
                self.sched.cancel()  # stop updating
            else:
                self.idle = 0
```

Note a reference to the scheduled update event is saved, so that the updates can be cancelled when the ball stops. The reversing of the velocity on a collision should emulate a non-elastic collision, so I have changed `*= -1` to `*= -0.75`. Finally, if the ball velocity is low enough that the ball does not move in a time interval, then consider the ball to have stopped.